# Hovering over increment/decrement value buttons on number input in React on Chrome causes continuos increase

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

Heres the scenario in which the bug occurs:

1. Open a react app in chrome browser
2. Hover over the input number field
3. click increment/decrement button

Then what happens is the value in the input will continue to increase/decrease as long as the mouse is hovered over the inc/dec buttons, even when you only clicked the inc/dec button once. This does not happen in firefox. The input html looks like this: `<input type="number" />`.

Comment: We almost certainly need more information to help you. Maybe a code snippet?

Comment: Please create a [mcve].

Answer (score 2):

I realize this is an old post, but I just ran into an identical problem in Chrome v80 and React 16.13.0.  The problem doesn't exist in other tested browsers (Firefox, Edge, Safari).

Here is cleaned-up code which causes a similar issue

```
<input 
  type="number"
  onChange = {e => {
    this.setState({ myvalue: e.target.value });
  }}
  value={this.state.myvalue}
/>
```

The solution is to force the focus away from the input box after an "onMouseUp" event on the input box by using blur().  You still need to keep focus on the input element when only a single mouse click is detected so you can still type in your values, otherwise the onMouseUp event will prevent you from ever having focus on the input box for typing.

```
<input type="number"
   onChange = {e => {
      this.setState({ myvalue: e.target.value });
   }}
   value={this.state.myvalue}
   onClick = {e => {
      e.target.focus();
   }}   
   onMouseUp = {e => {
     e.target.blur();
   }
/>
```

This still allows you to hold the mouse button down on the up/down value arrows and they work as intended.

I'm not sure why this issue persists in Chrome but there is something up with the way the mouse events are handled in Chrome vs the other browsers.

Comment: Its not just react.  I'm using `lit` and i've implemented a custom element around inputs and was experiencing the same problem in chrome.  With my custom element I was able to handle it within the custom element, without needing any changes elsewhere